# SOCK_RAW permissions for www-data

Tags: php, ubuntu, permissions, raw-sockets

Does anybody knows how to grant SOCK_RAW permissions for the www-data user ?

as this is required for an ICMP request from php side !
as this code `$socket  = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, 1);` won't work without these permissions !

Thank you .